# WPF - How to get canvas position on mouse click independently of the resolution and resizing

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, canvas

I found a lot on this subject for HTML 5 JavaScript ([like so](http://www.ckollars.org/canvas-two-coordinate-scales.html)), but I have found nothing over WPF.

I have a canvas that we are creating for selecting points over a image in that canvas.

The canvas element in XAML is very simple:

```
        <Canvas x:Name="Cnv" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" />
```

We are getting the coordinates from mouse click like so:

```
        Point p = Mouse.GetPosition(Cnv);
```

Then, we draw something on that point:

```
        ellipse = new Ellipse();
        ellipse.Fill = Brushes.Transparent;
        ellipse.Width = 20;
        ellipse.Height = 20;
        ellipse.Stroke = Brushes.Gray;
        ellipse.StrokeThickness = 1;

        Cnv.Children.Add(ellipse);
        Canvas.SetLeft(ellipse, p.X-9);
        Canvas.SetTop(ellipse, p.Y-5);
```

The problem here is, if the user resizes his screen, the canvas will also resize. And of course, the coordinates won't be right anymore.

Is there a way to draw this ellipse in a more "relative" position to the canvas? And how do I proper resize my canvas, considering these points? Is there a event handler for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use a Viewbox and take care that the Image size is the native pixel size of its Source bitmap.

```
<Viewbox>
    <Grid>
        <Image Source="..."
               Width="{Binding Source.PixelWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
               Height="{Binding Source.PixelHeight, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
               MouseDown="ImageMouseDown"/>
        <Canvas x:Name="canvas"/>
    </Grid>
</Viewbox>
```

The mouse event handler places an Ellipse at the click position, regardless of the scaling, and the click position (and Ellipse size) is in bitmap pixel coordinates:

```
private void ImageMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    var pos = e.GetPosition((IInputElement)sender);

    var ellipse = new Ellipse
    {
        Width = 20,
        Height = 20,
        Fill = Brushes.Magenta
    };

    Canvas.SetLeft(ellipse, pos.X - 10);
    Canvas.SetTop(ellipse, pos.Y - 10);
    canvas.Children.Add(ellipse);
}
```

Comment: That's a very alternative. I'll try it out and I'll mark as a answer if it works!

Comment: Perfection. It works fine! Even on scaling up and down. Thanks a lot!